# Confusion with ID's in datalist

Tags: html, html-datalist

I have a question about `datalist` in HTML.

I've read "In short, the `name` is the identifier that is sent to the server when you submit the form. The `id` is a unique identifier for the browser, clientside, for javascript and such."

Why then does the `datalist` not need a `name`? It doesn't need a `name` to identify it when it is submitted to the form?

```
<p><label>
  <span> Data List: </span>
  <input type=text list=someList>
  <datalist id=someList>
    <option label=First value="First">
    <option label=Second value="Second">
    <option label=Third value="Third">
  </datalist>
</label></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `<datalist>` is just a list of options that can be displayed and selected from in an `<input>` element. The `<input>` element must be named for the selected value to be submitted.